# How can I enable my errors to show the line and file the error is in

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How can I log errors with the file name and line?

Using Node 11.2.0

```
(node:208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
  at item.request.gen.end (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09ff3c4a-1318-4254-9aec-024d6a83c316/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.4.2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:79:15)
  at then (/rbd/pnpm-volume/09ff3c4a-1318-4254-9aec-024d6a83c316/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/snekfetch/3.6.4/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21
  at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

(node:208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not 
handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 478)
```

Comment: `internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7` did you look in this file at line 77? 7 is the position on the line

Comment: I have never accessed that file and I'm pretty sure I have never seen it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to log errors with that below piece that shows where the error occured, just use `console.trace(err)`.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
if (message.content === 'hi') {
  message.channel.send(text)
    .catch(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`error:`, err);
      }
    });
}
```

Result:

```
(node:9683) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: text is not defined
```

Comment: Yea I know that, I need to know where the error was because I have a very big project